# Solving a closure pattern with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a class containing two methods. The first takes a callback function and loops over a set of values,  and for each that satisfies a condition it executes the callback with two parameters:

```
...
public mapShapeMatrix(callback): void {
    let row = 0, col = 0;

    for (let bit = 0x8000; bit > 0; bit = bit >> 1) {
        if (this.dirs[this.currentDir] & bit) {
            callback(col, row);
        }
        if (++col === 4) {
            col = 0;
            ++row;
        }
    }
}
...
```

I then have another method which calls the first and passes it a callback:

```
...
private collide(boardMatrix): boolean {
    this.mapShapeMatrix(
        (col: number, row: number) => {
            if ((boardMatrix[row + this.offset.y] &&
                boardMatrix[row + this.offset.y][col + this.offset.x]) !== 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    )
    return false;
}
...
```

Then later on I am calling the collide function to check whether it returned true or false:

```
if (this.collide(boardMatrix)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The problem is, as expected, that the callback returns true within its own scope, and does not return from the collide function. Normally I would solve this with a closure pattern, but it's not so easy with TypeScript. Storing the call to this.mapShapeMatrix in a variable means that the collide function is not returning a boolean, and if its return type is not a boolean then the call to this.collide complains about checking for truthiness against the wrong type.

Essentially I'm looking to find out if there is a way in TypeScript to write this kind of pattern, and if not, is there a different solution?

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: `collide` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question correctly, you need to change the methods to return booleans as mapShapeMatrix doesn't return anything. You can then check the returned values, something like:

```
type CB = (x: number, y: number) => boolean

public mapShapeMatrix(callback: CB): boolean {
    let row = 0, col = 0

    for (let bit = 0x8000; bit > 0; bit = bit >> 1) {
        if (this.dirs[this.currentDir] & bit) {
            if (callback(col, row)) {
                return true
            }
        }

        if (++col === 4) {
            col = 0
            ++row
        }
    }

    return false
}

private collide(boardMatrix): boolean {
    return this.mapShapeMatrix(
        (col: number, row: number) => {
            if ((boardMatrix[row + this.offset.y] &&
                boardMatrix[row + this.offset.y][col + this.offset.x]) !== 0) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    )
    return false
}
```

Comment: Doesn't returning in mapShapeMatrix interrupt the for loop?

Comment: Yes, if you don't interrupt the loop, what value do you want to collide() to return? The callback is called multiple times so which value do you want to use?